# Atualizar campo de tabela mesmo se entrada for igual ao definido

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados e estou executando normalmente operações de inserte, delete, update, select. Durante um teste fui executar um update de um campo com a mesma informação que está definido na base de dados e me gerou uma falha. Existe alguma maneira de executar com sucesso o update em um campo, mesmo se o que está definido for igual ao input?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito pouco clara. Leia ela como se vc fosse outro usuário, vc entenderia 100% a pergunta, sem exemplos nem nada? Ajuda nóis aí :)

Comment: Qual foi a falha? Não existe problema em atualizar uma coluna com os mesmos dados, apesar de ser uma boa prática fazer com que a aplicação identifique se houve ou não alteração antes de executar o `update`.